# What are class relations?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody give brief idea of class relations?

Comment: Can you link to where you encountered the term "class relations", so we can have some context?

Comment: Class relations refer to the relation ships (they're boats!) that exist between people with large amounts of money, and those less fortunate.

Comment: Sorry but @Jimmy is completely wrong here, class relations refer to us, the code monkeys, being the peons or serfs.

Comment: I though it was to do with school room crushes?

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa, @Nick Craver - you're both wrong, it's about class objects going from public to private to merge and make new classes.

Comment: @Joel: This is where input validation is _critical_.  Make sure you use a good dependency injection container.

Comment: @David - tru dat. Regular Expressions are not optimal for input validation in these cases. You have to utilize specialized validation methods.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the term is referring to the type of relationship between two classes, for example:

- inheritance: class B has an *is a* relationship with class A when B extends A
- composition: class B has a *has a* relationship with class A when B contains an instance of A in its properties
- dependency: class B has a *uses* relationship with class A when B takes a reference to A and invokes some method on it

Comment: Don't forget the obvious and most common: no relationship whatsoever...

Comment: Well....ok yeah sure this is *correct* and all, but it's not nearly as fun :)

Comment: You're forgetting one, the hate relationship, it's when class B continuously calls the destructor on class A, no matter how much resources class A gives to class B

Comment: @Nick - to be fair, I *did* vote up Jimmy Hoffa's comment.